# -bash: printf: `words[0]': not a valid identifier

Tags: terminal

input `cd XX` in terminal, next press `TAB` .
I want to complete the file path.
error:
`-bash: printf:`words[0]': not a valid identifier
-bash: printf: `words[1]': not a valid identifier -bash: printf:` words[2]': not a valid identifier
-bash: compopt: command not found
`

I want to complete the file path.